# Pausing in GNU parallel and waiting for character

Tags: gnu-parallel, user-input

I would like the timing pause to be replaced with the equivalent of a getchar() in a GNU parallel execution:

```
parallel -j2 --halt 2 ::: 'sleep 5m; return 1' './runMe'
```

However the following does not work (it finishes the execution of the first job immediately):

```
parallel -j2 --halt 2 ::: 'read -n1 kbd; return 1' '/runMe'
```

Is there another way than just waiting?
NB: ./runMe contains an infinite loop.

Comment: `parallel -p ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU Parallel can run interactively using `-p`.

```
parallel -p echo ::: 1 2 3
```

You will have to answer `y` every time, but maybe that is good enough.

Also be aware that any output will be delayed. When running 3 jobs in parallel, the output of job 1 will be printed after starting job 3.